# How would a hacker be able to spoof their IP when logging into a private FTP server?

Tags: networking, ip, ftp, ip-address, spoofing

If, somehow, someone gains access to one of the users on my FTP server, I would still be able to see their IP address and trace it to them. However, I fear that it might be possible for them to spoof their IP address when logging in. Is this possible, and how would they do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, They can spoof their IP.

The obvious one - as mentioned in the comments is to use a VPN, however there are more other ways, which boil down to the same thing - use an intermediary server.  These include -

- Virtual Machines set up with SSH.
- Proxy servers which support FTP.
- Hacked websites with scripts to run FTP from those boxes.
- Use a jump box / Bastion / SSH gateway.
- Hacked systems the ftp user has compromised.